# Cakephp 3 query string build encoded &

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.4

I'm using CakePHP 3.5 [Url Helper](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/url.html) to generate some Urls to be called using jQuery Ajax. I have the following Ajax:

```
$(".container").on("change", "#select_box", function(){
                url = '<?= $this->Url->build(["controller" => "tools", "action" => "getTools", "?" => ["param1" => "PARAM1_PLACEHOLDER", "param2" => "PARAM2_PLACEHOLDER"]]); ?>';

            url = url.replace("PARAM1_PLACEHOLDER", $(this).val()).replace("PARAM2_PLACEHOLDER", 5);

            $("#tools").load(url);
        });
```

And for some reason, my url is coming up like this

```
/tools/get-tools/param1=1&amp;param2=5 (with &amp; instead of &)
```

Because of that, when I use getQuery('param2') to get the value of query string parameter param2, I get null.

Any help please? Isn't this the way that I'm supposed to build url with query string parameters in CakePHP 3.5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the second parameter to not escape the `&`:

```
$this->Url->build([
    "controller" => "tools",
    "action" => "getTools",
    "?" => [
        "param1" => "PARAM1_PLACEHOLDER",
        "param2" => "PARAM2_PLACEHOLDER"
    ]
], ['escape' => false]);
```